# how much larger is the scope of the Lebesgue integral (than the Riemann integral)?

Tags: measure-theory

I know that all Riemann integrable functions are Lebesgue integrable and that there are more Lebesgue integrable functions out there than Riemann integrable functions, but how significant of a difference is it?  Are there vastly more Lebesgue integrable families of functions that are not Riemann integrable?  Or are there just a few families more?

Comment: In some ways there are vastly more (various Baire category and other notions of "greater"), and in other ways not (each class of functions has the same cardinality).

Comment: I thought you were doing a phd in integration